# Accesing the internet through work computer with ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have OpenSSH running on ubuntu on my work computer and I can access it through `ssh user@123.234.244.34` from my ubuntu laptop.

Now I just want to access the internet on the laptop as if I were at work, to get access to subscription sites that are otherwise behind paywalls.

What is the easiest way to do this (without using `ssh -X` and starting a lagging browser)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest setting up a SOCKS proxy. This is very easily set-up by adding the option -D *portnumber* to the command you command you gave in your post. Then, you can configure your browser to use a SOCKS proxy with server *localhost* and portnumber the number your provided in the ssh command.

This way, your browser will refer to your own proxy which is on your ubuntu machine at your work.

Comment: Yes, that worked directly! Thank you very much. If anyone else views this, i can give the tip that in Firefox go to `edit > preferences > advanced > Network > "Settings" button right of "Connections"` then check `Manual proxy configuration` and put `localhost` in the `SOCKS host` field, and in the `Port` field put the number (ex 7563) that you chose previously on the command line (ex`ssh -D 7563 user@123.234.244.34`).

Comment: For completeness: With `ssh -fND 7563 user@123.234.244.34` the process goes into the background and doesn't occupy the shell. Only way to kill it in this case seem to be to find the pid with `ps aux | grep 7563` and `kill pid-number`.

Answer (score 0):

If your work has a proxy server, set up an SSH tunnel to the corporate proxy server from your client and then tell your local browser to use the proxy on your local machine (which the SSH client will then re-route to the remote proxy).

See http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html

If they don't and it's for a small range of sites, modify your hosts file so it thinks the site is running on your machine and set up an SSH tunnel to the remote site.